# scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am trying to call a method after my scroll animation is complete. I have a Table View and I set the delegate in viewDidLoad like this`self.tableView.delegate = self` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174803/event-scrolling-scrollviewdidscroll-never-called-swift-3) , but that didn't help.

Basically, If a button is clicked, it scrolls up to a specific cell, lets call it the start cell, in the table view if the start cell is not visible. I'm using the scrollToRow method for the scrolling and animation

```
tableViewController.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: techniqueNo, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
```

Once this scroll animation is complete, I want to add an animation to the start cell. I tried adding this method from the scroll view delegate, but it isn't getting called

```
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("animation Complete")
}
```

Any idea why this method is not getting called?

Note: This is different from [UITableView is done scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521681/how-to-check-when-uitableview-is-done-scrolling) because
(1) this is swift and that answer is Objective-C, and 
(2) I have tried implementing the method from the delegate to check if the animation finished, but its not getting called and I need help figuring out why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check when UITableView is done scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521681/how-to-check-when-uitableview-is-done-scrolling)

Comment: Not a duplicate because this is swift, and I have tried implementing the method from the delegate to check if the animation finished, but I can't see why its not getting called

Comment: Maybe because your cell is already in the required position?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this what you need?

Add these funcs to your table view controller...

**Edit:** forgot to include the `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` ...

```
override func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollingFinish()
}

override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollingFinish()
}

override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if !decelerate {
        scrollingFinish()
    }
}

func scrollingFinish() -> Void {
    print("Scroll Finished!")
}
```

Comment: I had the function declaration wrong. I didn't have the override or the underscore

Comment: Also, I forgot to add the `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` func override (needed for `.scrollToRow()`).